# Unique ID Generation in java

Tags: java

Giving a Input String, the string length will not more than 30, the output will be a unique id number. Is there a way in Java can do this?the same string will always generate the same id, different string can not generate the same id.  the java HashCode() can do this ?

thanks

Comment: hashCode() is what you want.  Or else apply a cryptographic hash to the string yourself.

Comment: Hash algorithms have collisions - although some of the better ones are incredibly far apart - so using that wouldn't feel right.

Comment: obviously not (hashcode is an int => only 2^32 possible values)

Comment: Is the string limited to certain characters? (alphanumeric for example)?

Comment: @Makoto -- Obviously, the only way to assure uniqueness when the number of combos can potentially exceed 2^23 is to keep a registry.  But a good hash (and Java hashCode for String is pretty good) should come close.

Comment: @HotLicks 'Unique' only has one meaning, and that isn't it. OP is going to need a number 0..2^240, unless the inputs have a restricted character set.

Comment: what is the meaning of restricted character set?

Comment: @snow8261 if you only know the string is up to 30 characters, that gives you 65536^30 possibilities (3.10^144) - if, on the other hand, you know that the characters are all small cap letters for example, you only have 26^30 possibilities (=2.8.10^42). In the second case, you could store the value in a long, in the first case, you will need something larger.

Comment: Yep, if the string is less than 30, and you restrict the character values to a small set (32 or 64 possible values) then you can manage with 30 * 5 (=150) or 30 * 6 (=180) bits.  Restricting only to a single case of alphabetic gets you down to about 141 bits.  (141 bits is a hair more than will fit in a standard "long".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To satisfy the requirement

> the same string will always generate the same id, different string can not generate the same id

you'll get pretty huge numbers. You require that the function will be [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) so you need as many numbers as the number of possible `String`s, which is something like $255^30$ in your case (or something like $65536^30$ if you allow arbitrary Unicode characters). So you'll need `BigInteger`s for that and certainly you use `int` (simply there are more `String`s of length up to 30 than numbers in `int`). For example, `new BigInteger(theString.getBytes(""))` satisfies your requirement.

If you use `hashCode`, you'll lose injectivity, but the chance that two `String`s will have the same `hashCode` is very low in most cases (it's actually the purpose of [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to make this chance low). If you want to be extra sure that the number of collisions uniformly small, you can use some [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), but still, the mapping won't be injective.

Perhaps explaining the reasons for your requirements would help finding the best solution.

Comment: for example, I want to add a device in my system,i need to generate a unique key for the name of the device, and i store the key in the database as the unique ID and treat it as the foreign key for other table. when i delete the device in my system,i want to add it back in the system, i will get the exact same id as before.

Comment: The safest approach is probably using the device name as the key. Or, to create a dictionary table that maps names to keys, and from which rows are never deleted, only inserted into (this way you could simply assign the keys incrementally). I assume deletions don't occur very often, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: maybe i just do not delete the record,just put some flag on it,so that i do not need to worry about id generation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java hashcode is not guaranteed to be unique. You need to look into UUID.

```
public static UUID nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Will it always return the same UUID for a given string?

Comment: @srini.venigalla -- True, but a random UUID will give a different value every time -- it's not tied to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit silly, but how about converting every character to ASCII number ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really truly need to be sure there are no collisions then the numbers you get will be enormous, certainly bigger than any of the primitive numeric types. My advice would be to use a SHA-1 hash which is almost certainly good enough (the Git version control system relies on the uniqueness of these hash values, are your requirements really stricter than theirs?)

If you want to guarantee uniqueness then I suppose one way you could do it would be to take the ASCII (or Unicode, depending on your input) numeric value for each character, padding it with zeroes so that all values have the same length, and then concatenating them all together into one big number. As stated previously there is no way you will fit this into a long value, so you will need to use the BigInteger class. The padding will be necessary to avoid collisions like '12 + 34' and '123 + 4'.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can restrict the set of valid strings in a deterministic way your only option is to interpret the whole string as your id. As you're going to obtain very large id's you should use the BigInteger class to represent them.

I'd convert characters in reverse order, so as not to have to worry about strings of different length.